# Get modified date of web resource in Java

Tags: java, url, date, urlconnection

How do you get the modified date of a web resource in Java?

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
// What now?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
long time = connection.getLastModified();
```

[Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getLastModified%28%29)

> Returns the value of the last-modified
>   header field. The result is the number
>   of milliseconds since January 1, 1970
>   GMT.

Comment: Indeed. To be clear: this information comes from HTTP [`Last-Modified`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) header. It's the server's responsibilty to set it. If it's absent, you can't reveal it and it will return 0.