# Compare Last Modified Java

Tags: java, compare, last-modified

I have two files, a local file and a file from an URL.

I wanna compare if the last modified from local file is older than the URL file.

```
File oldFile = new File("local file");
URL newFile = new URL("url file");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) newFile.openConnection();

if(oldFile.lastModified() < httpCon.getLastModified()){
   //do something
}
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: .getLastModified() is getting me "0".

Comment: [See this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095775/get-modified-date-of-web-resource-in-java#comment3174241_3095788)